# Delta Lake Time Travel with Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

We have Delta Lake tables that are populated with data using Structured Streaming. I am trying to understand how Delta Time Traveling works when it comes to Structured Streaming checkpoints.

Let's say Table B is reading from Table A. Table B is on version 100 and it processes a microbatch using structured streaming resuming from checkpoint X. Table B is then on version 101 after the microbatch is processed and the checkpoint is updated to be some checkpoint Y.

If I want to time travel on Table B from version 101 to 100, I would also like the checkpoint to go back from checkpoint Y to checkpoint X also.

Does the checkpoint get automatically rolled back when Table B is rolled back to a previous version using time travel?

If the checkpoint does not roll back along with Table B, then Table B will be on version 100 and the checkpoint will still refer to checkpoint Y. However, the source data between checkpoint X and checkpoint Y will never be processed in Table B after the rollback creating a gap in the data.

How can we ensure that structured streaming checkpoints are updated when time travel is used on the table?

Answer (score 0):

These two things are not connected in any way. Checkpoint is the way Spark knows where it is in structured stream and is used for other formats as well. It is not table it is just file (or more files) which are overwritten. So checkpoint is completely independent of what you wrote to delta table (you may actually not write anything, while still progressing in structured stream and updating checkpoints).

What I see as solution here is the option which is available for structured streams in delta, called `startingVersion`. This is basically version for source table where you start your streaming from. You will parametrize this option and if you revert data to version 100 you will set this to 100 and clear checkpoint completely. This should just stream changes from version 100.

Comment: The startingVersion option is set to read on the source table, not the sink table. In this case, we wouldn't use startingVersion 100 because that's the version on the sink. We would need to use the version of the source that was used to populate the sink at version 100. Because checkpoints are used, we don't know what startingVersion to use after doing time travel on the sink table.